# Access denied on libraries after disaster recovery

Tags: permissions, disaster-recovery

after disaster recovery I am not able to upload new documents to the libraries; I always get access denied despite I am a farm admin.

What I did:

- Installed Sharepoint with a new administration DB
- Created Web Applications as they were before
- Attached original content DB to Web application
- Configured User Profile Synchronization

It seems to me that in the original Content DB there are user rights which do not exist anymore in the new administration DB.

Is there a way to "reset" all the user permissions or to repair them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Being a Farm admin doesn't give you any rights to Site Collections.

But it enables you to give yourselves any rights. The two main options are:

- Central Admin | Application Management | Change site collection administrators
- Central Admin | Manage web Applications | User Policy (in ribbon)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was already site collection administrator and I also have the necessary rights in the "User Policy" but still the same problem. I tried also to create a new library in an existing site but again "access denied". If I create a new site and in there a library then it works. There must be something broken with the user rights...